# Mulit-session in iOS 8 with External Accessories

Tags: ios8, external-accessory

@WDC14 Apple said that iOS8 will now provide multi-session support (i.e. multiple apps each using the same protocol)can each   for external accessories but I can't find any detailed information on what exactly this means. In my case, we have a Bluetooth Classic accessory to which establish a BT connection.

What does it mean to say that each app using the same protocol can open a session to the same accessory? Does that mean that iOS 8 manages a single BT connection to a BT device and broadcasts all events from the accessory to each of the incoming streams. Or, does the accessory have to support a separate BT connection for each of the sessions that are opened with it?